# Is adding elements between elements with Jython and dom4j possible?

Tags: jython, dom4j

Just playing with dom4j, excellent. I was a PHP developer for a year and half, just got a new job and started playing around with Jython now I have spare time, its a great language.  Was thinking about trying to add a element in between element, example below:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Some text in here</p>
    <!--New p tag here-->
    <p>Some text in here</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to insert another **p** tag in between the two without converting the DOM to a string and back to DOM again as this is the only way I have been able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about dom4j specifically, but I would do it like this:

1. Copy all child nodes of `div#content` into a list, then delete its children.
2. Insert the first node back into the `div#content` node.
3. Insert the new `p` node into the `div#content` node.
4. Insert the last node back into the `div#content` node.

I don't know what this would be in terms of the DOM, but if nodes are represented as Jythonic objects, then it should be easy to do this.